# Search Results: How To Expand All Results In "List View"?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse has a "Show As List" option for a ctrl+H search ( multi file ). You get this option by going to the far right corner of the Search View and clicking the triangle icon.

The list is composed of list the files where the desired string was found, stating the number of hits in each file:

HelloWorld.java com.acme.first (3 matches ) Utilities.java com.acme.first (4 matches ) SomeClass.java com.acme.first (2 matches )

Is there any way to get Eclipse to expand those results, while still showing it all in a list? For example, actually showing me each of the 3 matches, in the Search View, from HelloWorld.java?

Comment: No, as I know. Switch to tree view

Comment: Eclipse is an extensible platform and in the _Search_ view results of different kind of Ctrl+H searches are displayed in different ways. Are you talking about a file search? Please provide an example of what you get and how and why(!) you want it to be different.